# Calling two different functions based on h:selectOneMenu value

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I am using MyFaces 2.0.12 and RichFaces 3.3.3. I need to be calling two different functions in BackBean (`Session scope`) when users changes the selection of `h:selectOneMenu`. Previously I did it like below:

```
    <h:selectOneMenu
         value="#{customer.recordsDisplayed}"                                       
        valueChangeListener="#{customer.onRecordsPerPageChange}"
        onchange="submit()"
        <f:selectItems value="#{customer.rppValues}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

and in backbean in:

```
    public void onRecordsPerPageChange(ValueChangeEvent vce){
        
        if(this.searchFlagAdvance)
            searchMethodA();
        else
            searchMethodB();
    }
```

I understand the above is wrong as **you're not meant to be calling logic or changing backbean values during ValueChangeEvent phase**.

so my question is what is the correct method? because of the above code i get into scenarios where the backbean values are null and whole thing falls flat.

### UPDATE:

I changed my code to below and works perfectly. I just want to know if below is good practice.

```
    public void onRecordsPerPageChange(ActionEvent event) {
         String value =(String) ((EditableValueHolder) event.getComponent().getParent()).getValue();
         
         this.value = value;
         if(searchFlagA)
            searchMethodA();
        else
            searchMethodB();
    }
```

and changed the JSP code to :

```
    <h:selectOneMenu
         id="selectRecordDisplay"
         value="#{customer.recordsDisplayed}"                         
        <f:selectItems value="#{customer.rppValues}" />
        <a4j:support event="onchange" actionListener="#{customer.onRecordsPerPageChange}" reRender="pangelgrid"></a4j:support> 
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: sorry for leaving that out - Yes . myFaces 2.0.12 and RichFaces 3.3.3. Updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using JSF 2.0, you can use ajax:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{customer.recordsDisplayed}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{customer.rppValues}" />
  <f:ajax action="#{customer.onRecordsPerPageChange}" 
          execute="idsToBeProcessed"
          render="idsToBeRendered"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

With the follogin action method:

```
public void onRecordsPerPageChange(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
 ...
}
```

Within the `execute` attribute  list the ids (space separated) of all components that need to be processed on the server side, especially the ones that your listener method depends on. The `render` attribute takes all component ids that need to be re-rendered when the ajax call returns. If you put `@form` in one or both attributes, the whole form will be processed/rendered.

Comment: i seem to have updated my question simultaneously as you provided an answer. can you please have a look at the update and compare the updated code with one provided by yourself?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Alternatively you can use the built-in ajax tag of JSF 2.0.